# Binding empty list via @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I'm using `@ConfigurationProperties` to bind config properties from a YAML file to java properties class.

In the properties class there is this field:

```
private List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> actionsBeforeIndexing;
```

It's intended to look like this in YAML:

```
actionsBeforeIndexing:
  - testAction:
    param: value
```

This works. But I want to be able to define empty lists like this too (action without parameters):

```
actionsBeforeIndexing:
  - testAction
```

or even like this (no action to be performed):

```
actionsBeforeIndexing:
```

When I try it with these empty lists I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>>>]
```

How to get this working? Maybe is there a way to force parsing this YAML option like a list even there is no list defined?

Answer (score 0):

Not really nice but working solution is to create two type converters:

```java
/**
 * Convert empty property in YAML to empty Map.
 *
 * parses this:
 *
 *   actionsBeforeIndexing:  -->  Map<String, Map<String, String>>
 */
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class ActionListPropertyConverter implements Converter<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> convert(String source) {

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        if (StringUtils.hasText(source)) {
            /*
             * parse action name without ending colon:
             *
             *   actionsBeforeIndexing:
             *   - testAction  -->  Map<String, String>
             */
            map.put(source, new HashMap<>());
        }

        return map;
    }
}

/**
 * Convert empty property in YAML to empty Map.
 *
 * parses this:
 *
 *   actionsBeforeIndexing:
 *   - testAction:  -->  Map<String, String>
 */
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class ActionParameterPropertyConverter implements Converter<String, Map<String, String>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> convert(String source) {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```